# FIle upload with Carrier wave returning :nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, attachment

I'm attempting to add carrierwave to my application to handle attachments from users (pdf, doc, etc - not images).  I've viewed several tutorials and while it seems to be working, I am not able to access the attachment through link_to method or by following the url carrierwave creates.  I'm running into two odd things when using my application:

1) The link preview (referring to the popup in the bottom left in chrome showing the destination of the link) only shows localhost::model/id, not the url that is in the uploader

2) When I view a record in the rails console, the column shows nil.  I have added this into my permitted params in the controller.

My controller:

```
  class Cms484sController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cms484, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /cms484s
  # GET /cms484s.json
  def index
    @cms484s = Cms484.all
  end

  # GET /cms484s/1
  # GET /cms484s/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cms484s/new
  def new
    @cms484 = Cms484.new
  end

  # GET /cms484s/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cms484s
  # POST /cms484s.json
  def create
    @cms484 = Cms484.new(cms484_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cms484.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cms484, notice: 'Cms484 was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cms484 }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cms484.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cms484s/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cms484s/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cms484.update(cms484_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cms484, notice: 'Cms484 was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cms484 }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cms484.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cms484s/1
  # DELETE /cms484s/1.json
  def destroy
    @cms484.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cms484s_url, notice: 'Cms484 was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cms484
      @cms484 = Cms484.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cms484_params
      params.require(:cms484).permit(:supplier_name, :supplier_addr, :supplier_city, :supplier_state, :supplier_zip, :frm_date, :document)
    end
end
```

My uploader:

```
    class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

      storage :file

      def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
      end
end
```

My form: (abbreviated)

```
<%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true %>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Complete Cms484" />
  </div>
<% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

My view:

```
<p>
  <strong>Sup name:</strong>
  <%= @cms484.supplier_name %>
</p>
<%= link_to 'Document', @cms484.document.url %>  |
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_cms484_path(@cms484) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', cms484s_path %>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carrierwave relies on the naming convention of your uploader class. In your case you named it FileUploader.

Adjust your permitted attributes from :document to :file

```
def cms484_params
  params.require(:cms484).permit(:supplier_name, :supplier_addr, :supplier_city, :supplier_state, :supplier_zip, :frm_date, :file)
end
```

In your view

```
<%= link_to 'Document', @cms484.file_url %>
```

Comment: Actually thought about this issue the next morning.  Sure enough, if you follow the convention like you're supposed to - everything works!  Thanks for your help